# using private API for authController and user model

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

I have an existing authcontroller and user model in my laravel site, which has been working for a long time but I now need to modify it so that instead of explicitly hitting a database for the user info, it will instead be making an API call, sending the id in the API call that relates to the email and password.

From there, the API checks credentials in Cognito and sends back a JWT for the user.

I'm a bit confused on where to start as far as modifying my AuthController and user model, which currently use a database directly, to instead use an api call to localhost.testapi.com/login/?id=9999

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $loginPath;
    protected $redirectPath;
    protected $redirectAfterLogout;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;

        $this->loginPath = route('auth.login');

        $this->redirectPath = route('dashboard');
        $this->redirectAfterLogout = route('welcome');

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');



        if (Auth::validate($credentials) ||
            (config('auth.passwords.master_pw')!=NULL && $request['password']==config('auth.passwords.master_pw'))) {
            $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
            if (!is_null($user) && $user->active) {
                Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            } else {
                return redirect(route('auth.login'))
                    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
            }
        }
         return redirect(route('auth.login'))
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }

models/user.php

    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use SoftDeletes, Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, HasRoles;


        protected $table = 'user_table';

        protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'cell'];

        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

        private static $users = [];

        public function resource()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Resource');
        }

        public function details()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\details', 'auth_attribute_user', 'user_id', 'attribute_id')->withPivot('details');
        }

        public static function getNames($userNum)
        {

            if (empty(User::$users)) {

                $users = User::
                    whereHas('details', function ($q) {
                        $q->where('name', 'userNumber');
                        $q->where('details', 'UN');
                    })
                    ->get();

                foreach ($users as $user) {
                    User::$users[$user->userNumber] = $user->Name;
                }

            }

            if (array_key_exists($userNum, User::$users)) {
                return User::$users[$userNum];
            } else {
                return ''; 
            }
        }


        public function getAccountTypeAttribute()
        {
            return $this->details()->where('name', 'userNumber')->first()->pivot->details;
        }
```

Comment: What version of laravel do you use?

Comment: We are pretty much holding tight on 5.2 right now

Comment: What's the response of the api? Is it a jwt for example? Is it just a true or false? Do you keep your own data in your database or you fetch all the data from the api though api call and the api is only for authentication or authorization?

Comment: The API is just for auth right now. It's response would be a JWT. So, we keep user data in the database but the api would check the username and password from the application, and API would check with cognito to ensure credentials are correct, then send back JWT for the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your responses in you comments, the way i prefer is this:
 1. Make the api call. Check Guzzle to make http requests. It is a nice library and i often use it;
 2. Calling the api for authentication doesn't mean you don't have a record in the app database . You need it to related your data to other tables. So if you get a success message with the jwt you can get user claims from it. If for example we suppose that you have as a unique identifier user's email you check if user already exists in your own db or you create it:

`$user = User::firstOrCreate($request->email, $data_you_need_and_you_get_from_claims);`

 3. Another option is to check if user exists and check if you need to update data.
 4. Login User

`Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));`

Hope it helps. Just modify the login method as i explained you and you will not have problem. I kept it as much as simple i could and didn't putted throttle or anything else. Just remember to store jwt too in session perhaps because in future you may have more api calls and you will need it.

Comment: Thank you I think that clears some of it up! In laravel, is there a preferred way to store the JWT in the session?

Comment: I prefer storing it in a cookie so i can have access with javascript but i think session is fine too.

Comment: Ok thank you. And just so I understand, on step 1 when you say make the api call, this would be within the login function of my AuthController right?

Comment: Yes i think it is a nice place. If not you have to remove the route or replace the controller so users cannot have access to the other way of validation.